# useMutation reload data after refetch

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am trying to reload my table of data once my useMutation has completed.

On page load i am querying:

```
const { loading: appLoading, data: applicationsData } = useQuery(
        applications.operations.GET_APPLICATIONS_BY_COMPANY,
    {
        client: applications.client,
        variables: { companyId: userDetails.companyId },
    }
)
```

when a user selects a button to clone a record:

```
const [
    CloneApplication,
    { loading: cloneLoading, data: cloneData, error: cloneError },
] = useMutation(applications.operations.CLONE_APPLICATION_BY_COMPANY, {
    client: applications.client,
    onCompleted: (data) => {
        setFinalData((prev) => [...prev, data]), console.log('data', data)
    },
})
```

im adding a record to the list but when i refresh its not there. My assumption is instead of adding it to state, I need to refetch the applications and then save that to state which in turn will automatically refresh the table.

My question is how can i do that?

Edit:

```
const { applications } = apis
const { queryString, parameters } = getTemplatesListApiDetails()
const [finalData, setFinalData] = useState<any>([])
const [templatesList, setTemplatesList] = useState([])

const { loading, data } = useQuery(queryString, parameters)

const { loading: appLoading, data: applicationsData } = useQuery(
    applications.operations.GET_APPLICATIONS_BY_COMPANY,
    {
        client: applications.client,
        variables: { companyId: userDetails.companyId },
    }
)

const [
    CloneApplication,
    { loading: cloneLoading, data: cloneData, error: cloneError },
] = useMutation(applications.operations.CLONE_APPLICATION_BY_COMPANY, {
    client: applications.client,
    refetchQueries: [
        { query: applications.operations.GET_APPLICATIONS_BY_COMPANY },
    ],
})

useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.getCompanyTemplates)
        setTemplatesList(
            userDetails.globalTemplates === false
                ? data.getCompanyTemplates
                : data.getAllTemplates
        )

    if (applicationsData && templatesList) {
        const newFinalData = getFinalData({
            applicationsList: applicationsData.getApplicationsByCompany,
            templatesList: templatesList,
        })
        setFinalData(newFinalData)
    }
}, [applicationsData, cloneData, data, templatesList])
```

getFinalData Function

```
export function getFinalData(request: {
    templatesList: GetAllTemplate[]
    applicationsList: GetApplicationsByCompany[]
}): FinalDataResponse[] {
    const templates = request.templatesList.map((template) => {
        const applicationsForTemplate = request.applicationsList.filter(
            (app) => app.templateId === template.templateId
        )
        return { ...template, applications: applicationsForTemplate }
    })
    const groupedData = _.chain(templates)
        .groupBy('templateId')
        .map((value, key) => {
            const templateName = _.chain(value)
                .groupBy('templateName')
                .map((value, key) => key)
                .value()

            const createdDate = _.chain(value)
                .groupBy('dateCreated')
                .map((value, key) => dayjs(key).format('ll'))
                .value()

            const lastModified = _.chain(value)
                .groupBy('lastModified')
                .map((value, key) => dayjs(key).format('ll'))
                .value()

            return {
                templateId: key,
                templateName: templateName[0],
                createdDate: createdDate[0],
                lastModified: lastModified[0],
                applications: value[0].applications,
            }
        })
        .value()

    const finalData = groupedData.map((object, index) => {
        return {
            ...object,
            totalApplications: object.applications.length,
        }
    })
    console.log('returning final data: ', finalData)
    return finalData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To refetch the data automatically, you need to invalidate the previously cached results. In apollo, this is done using `refetchQueries`:

```js
useMutation(applications.operations.CLONE_APPLICATION_BY_COMPANY, {
  refetchQueries: [{ query: applications.operations.CLONE_APPLICATION_BY_COMPANY}]
})
```

More ways of solving this here: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/caching/when-to-use-refetch-queries/

Comment: Thanks for that information, i've tried that and while it does seem to refresh the table (so to speak) the "cloned" information is still not showing until refresh. Is there a way for me to run a function after the refetchQuery with that refetched data?

Comment: What is the purpose of `setFinalData((prev) => [...prev, data])`? is `finalData` what you display? You should be displaying `applicationsData` and let it refresh the data by itself.

Comment: Knayazev i've updated the OP with code. The reason its set to Final Data is because I need to restructure the response before using it.

Comment: If your useEffects are used to essentially cache data, use `useMemo` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to call getFinalData after the refetchQuery?